# SQL remove duplicate rows based on other rows

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have two tables (one that shows a record of all the programs sent to a customer, and another that shows a record of all the programs the user took action on). My ultimate goal is to count how many of those programs that were sent to the user were acted upon. I have a way of doing that right now but there is a problem. The programs may be sent to the user multiple times (I will use 20 for an example) within a single day. If the user takes action on that program within 24 hours, I don't want it to count as 19 programs that weren't acted on and 1 program that was acted on. I want it to count as 1 acted upon program with 0 fails.

The table that contains the programs sent to the customer needs to be filtered down so that each program that is sent to the customer only shows once per 24 hour period.

My solution is to have a "window" type thing so that once a program is sent to a customer, it is 'locked' for that customer for 24 hours so it won't appear in my 'programs sent to customer' query multiple times.

I have a table like this:

```
Customer    Time    Program
-----------------------------------
1           8:05    a
1           10:30   a
1           11:30   a
1           12:30   b
1           1:25    a
2           9:38    b
2           10:38   c
2           1:36    c
2           2:40    c
2           3:41    b
.
.
.
```

I want to get a table (query, not delete) that removes duplicate programs per customer within a certain time frame (confusing! I know)

Here is what I want (with a 3hr time frame for example):

```
Customer    Time    Program
-----------------------------------
1           8:05    a
1           11:30   a
1           12:30   b
2           9:38    b
2           10:38   c
2           2:40    c
2           3:41    b
.
.
.
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: what kind of column is "Time" datetime, timestamp, etc???  also what rdbms and version are you using?

Comment: And what is the datatype of `Time`? It's going to be really hard - for any code - to identify that `1:36` is *after* `10:38`.

Comment: Oracle. SQL Developer

Comment: Its a datetime. so its like 10-JAN-13 05:12:47

Comment: @hockeyplayer0623 - Which one in program A is duplicate in your example? How can you tell?  Why 10:30 is duplicate but not 11:30? It seems you want to remove a record based on the time only, not duplicate.

Comment: Please define what you mean by a "rolling window".

Comment: So it counts as a duplicate if it is within 3 hours from "closing" instance of the same program. so the 8:05 program happened and now boom anything within 3 hours from 8:05 doesn't count. As soon as 11:05 hits that program is open again. So now the 11:30 instance of program A hit, so now that closes the "window" for the next 3 hours. Thats what I am shooting for.

Comment: And that "window" that I am talking about is per program. So program B can happen at 8:10 and that would be perfectly fine but now program B's window is closed for the next 3 hours.

Comment: If no answer solved your problem, clarify here, don't post a new identical question. Sorry if this is conflicting with other advice you got but new question means you have a new problem, at least a bit different than an existing solved one.

Comment: they literally just told me to create a new question.

Comment: Well, they were wrong.

Comment: I meant to ask that new question differently and I ended up asking the same thing. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select *
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2
                  where t2.customer = t.customer and
                        t2.program = t.program and
                        t2.time - t.time < 3.0/24 and
                        t2.time > t.time
                 )
```

Date time arithmetic depends on databases, but this works for many of them.

Comment: This is on the right direction but it will not show the wanted results.

Comment: @ypercube . . . I assume you are referring to the "same program" part of the question.  I just added that in.

Comment: No. Besides that, it's not what the OP wants. The "rolling window" requirement can be solved only with a recursive query, I think.

Comment: @ypercube . . . I do not read the question that way.  And, the second line of "a" in the desired output supports my reading of the question.

Comment: I think the desired output suggests removal of programs which are with three hours of a preceding instance.  So I support thi ssolution.  But of course the OP's requirements are incomplete and confusing, so who can tell?

Comment: I am going to mark this as the correct answer because it is really close to what I want. The 'moving window' that is only possible with the recursive function is just not going to happen because I ran the recursive one for about an hour and got impatient so I gave up on that. Thank you @ypercube gordon

Comment: @hockeyplayer0623 . . . Post *another* question with a better description of the rolling timeframe (I missed the comment section).  I think there might be a solution, but I would like to see sample data for it.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion Gordon. I really could use the rolling or this technique and I am not sure which one is better, but I believe this will be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you mean can be solved (only) with a recursive query. Here is a solution:

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT 
        customer, program, time,
        ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (PARTITION BY customer, program
                  ORDER BY time)
          AS rn, 
        MIN(time) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY customer, program
                  ORDER BY time 
                  RANGE BETWEEN 3.0/24 FOLLOWING 
                            AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
          AS next_time
    FROM a
  )

SELECT 
    customer, time, program
FROM 
    cte
START WITH rn = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR customer = customer
       AND PRIOR program = program
       AND PRIOR next_time = time
ORDER BY 
    customer, time, program ;
```

You can also replace `MIN(time)` with `FIRST_VALUE(time)` above and get the same results. It might be more efficient.

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/14cd6/1)**

The efficiency on a big table is probably not going to be very good. You can try running the query with smaller set of data.

And you should at least add this index, so it does an index scan:

```
CREATE INDEX ix                -- choose a name for the index
  ON tableX                    -- the table name
  (customer, program, time) ;
```

You could also skip the final ordering or change it so it is more similar to the used index:

```
ORDER BY 
    customer, program, time ;
```